# Parallel Quicksort

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, quick-sort, sorting

As my [parallel mergesort implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/7684/15094) was very memory dependent, I wanted to write a parallel quicksort one. Here it comes:

```
template<class In>
In partition(In b, In e) {
    // create uniform distribuiton for random engine
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rand_distribution(0, std::distance(b, e - 1));

    // call static random engine to get index of random pivot
    tbb::spin_mutex::scoped_lock lock;
    lock.acquire(mutex);
    auto rand_pivot_index = rand_distribution(rand_engine);
    lock.release();

    // put pivot to last place in range
    std::swap(*(b + rand_pivot_index), *(e - 1));

    // save pivot value
    auto pivot = *(e - 1);
    auto pivotiterator = b;

    // sort the range
    for(auto it = b; it != e - 1; ++it) {
        if(*it < pivot) {
            std::swap(*it, *pivotiterator);
            ++pivotiterator;
        }
    }

    // put pivot to its according position and return position
    std::swap(*(pivotiterator), *(e - 1));
    return pivotiterator;
}


template<class In>
void quick_sort_parallel(In b, In e) {
    if (b != e) {
        In m = partition(b, e);

        // switch to different sort on worst case or smaller ranges
        if(std::distance(b, m) > 500) {
            tbb::parallel_invoke([&] { quick_sort_parallel(b, m); }, 
                                 [&] { quick_sort_parallel(m + 1, e); });
        }
        else 
            merge_sort_parallel(b, e); //defined somewhere else, pretty standard
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Code

I would suggest using RAII for your lock.

Instead of:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rand_distribution(0, std::distance(b, e - 1));

// call static random engine to get index of random pivot
tbb::spin_mutex::scoped_lock lock;
lock.acquire(mutex);
auto rand_pivot_index = rand_distribution(rand_engine);
lock.release();

// put pivot to last place in range
std::swap(*(b + rand_pivot_index), *(e - 1));
```

Use:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rand_distribution(0, std::distance(b, e - 1));

// call static random engine to get index of random pivot
int rand_pivot_index;
{
    tbb::spin_mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
    rand_pivot_index = rand_distribution(rand_engine);
}

// put pivot to last place in range
std::swap(*(b + rand_pivot_index), *(e - 1));
```

This ensures that if rand_distribution throws, the lock is released correctly.

### Algorithm

Choice of pivot is important in any quick-sort algorithm, and even more so in the parallel case, when you want to garuntee a good distribution of load over cores by avoiding unbalanced recursion.

A good basic strategy is to choose the median of k random elements as your pivot.

Taking this further, using a [median of medians algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm) can guarantee your quicksort a O(n log n) running time.

The correct approach and value of k will largely depend on the inputs your function will expect to take (e.g. adapt k based on size on input).

Comment: Of course RAII is the way to manage locks. Today I would do it all a little bit different anyway. Concerning the median of median thing, I don't understand how you can guarantee O(n log n) on an array of only dupes.

Comment: If your input can have non distinct elements then you also need your partition step to split into three. 1: (< pivot), 2: (= pivot), 3: (> pivot). Then recurse on 1 and 3. This will get you to O(n log n).

Comment: from where `rand_engine` come from?

Comment: @MORTAL from the original question - it's an unimportant implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, how your pseudo-random number generator is declared does matter, for depending on how it is declared, you may avoid using a lock to generate random numbers. Generating a random number is alreadu an expensive operation, so locking them makes it really expensive.

If you make your pseudo-random number generator `thread_local`, you don't need to lock anything anymore before generating a random number, it will be inherently thread-safe:

```
thread_local std::random_device rd;
thread_local std::mt19937 gen(rd());
```

Moreover, if you also make `thread_local` your `std::uniform_int_distribution`, you won't have to update it every time you call `partition`, but only once in each thread. That said, you can't initialize it with its "range" anymore, you have to pass it when you call it:

```
// Initialize it once
thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rand_distribution{};

// Call it
using param_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type;
auto rand_pivot_index = rand_distribution(gen, {0, std::distance(b, e - 1)});
```

If I didn't make any error while writing the code (untested), this should be thread-safe, lock-free and faster than your original solution :)

Comment: That's a good idea these days. Guess `thread_local` wasn't even supported back in 2012.

Comment: @inf Oh yeah, the question is becoming a bit old. I know that GCC and CLang have supported an almost equivalent `__thread` for a while, but I guess it took a bit longer to MSVC :)